# NLua - How to add new functions to a userdata through Lua?

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface, nlua

I'm trying to define a new function for my `Player` class which was defined in C#. The purpose of Lua in my project (a game engine) is to define custom behavior for entities such as players.

However, when I do `DoFile(fileName)` on the Lua file, it crashes with this exception:

"field or property 'Idle' does not exist"

It specifically points to the first line in this chunk of code:

```
function Player:Idle()
    self:Turn()
    self.StateType = StateType.Stand
    self.MoveType = MoveType.Idle
    self.Vel = Vector2.Zero
    if self.Anim.Number ~= 0 and (self.Anim.Number ~= 5 or self:GetAnimTime() == 0) then
        self:ChangeAnim(0)
    end
end
```

It seems to have a problem with writing `Player:Idle`. However, I also tried writing it as `Player.Idle` and I get the same issue. Here's how I handle loading the scripts for the player in C#:

```
        state["Player"] = this;

        // Load the states
        for (int j = 0; j < stateFiles.Length; j++)
        {
            string fp = filePath + @"\" + stateFiles[j];

            // If it's common, then if it doesn't exist, use the default.
            if (stateFiles[j] == "common.lua" && !File.Exists(fp))
                fp = Path.Combine("Content", "common.lua");

            // Now load it
            var f = state.DoFile(fp);
        }
```

I'm setting the Player global to `this` because this is the player class, so any new functions need to be declared in the context of `Player`. What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit**

I've solved the error from earlier, but I'm still not getting the results I want. It seems it's not possible to directly do this; however I've read up and it seems in Lua 5.2, there's a way to do something like this by associating a table with the userdata object through `debug.setuservalue`. However, when I tried using it, the table was still empty (even though the userdata was not).

This is what I tried (C#):

```
        state.NewTable("Player");
        state["tmp"] = this;
        state.DoString("a = debug.setuservalue(tmp, Player)");
        var t = state["Player"]; // Shows that Player is an empty table
        var a = state["a"]; // Shows that a was indeed set.
```

In other words, I want to be able to use `self` in the script to be able to refer to the userdata, as well as custom functions, such as `Idle()` and `Turn()`.

How can I achieve the behavior I desire?

Comment: I'm in now way an expert in `nlua` but according to [this](http://nlua.org/) shouldn't you first use the `LoadCLRPackage` and then the `.state.dostring` to create a .net property, since `Player`  was defined as a `c#` class?

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. What I want to know is whether or not it's possible to add Lua functions to predefined .NET objects in Lua. I've been reading for a few hours and it seems that's not technically possible, but I've read about something called `debug.setuservalue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Lua reference manual: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1

> Userdata values cannot be created or modified in Lua, only through the
>   C API. This guarantees the integrity of data owned by the host
>   program.

So you cannot add functions to userdata but you write your own, extended interface by wrapping the userdata in your own Lua table.

Simple example, assuming you can create a Player userdata value by calling Player().

```
WrappedPlayer = {}
WrappedPlayer.usrdata = Player()
function WrappedPlayer:Idle()
  self.usrdata:Turn()
  self.usrdata.MoveType = MoveType.Idle
end
```

Then you can simply call `WrappedPlayer:Idle()`

Of course you can further improve this and after overwriting the Player table with your own and adding some metatable magic you could simply create your very own Player object:

```
local myPlayer = Player()
myPlayer:Idle()
```

Just read some Lua OOP tutorials to find out how.

Not to forget a very simple solution:

```
function SetPlayerIdle(player)
  player:Turn()
  -- and so forth
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The hint you gave about using metatables was certainly the way I needed to go! I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232680/lua-metatables-and-metamethod-how-to-call-a-different-member-function) which also got me one step closer to achieving what I wanted! If you can, please check out my [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49220242/lua-why-are-c-functions-returned-as-userdata).