# Lua - Why are C functions returned as userdata?

Tags: c, lua, lua-api, metatable

I'm working on game scripting for my engine and am using a metatable to redirect functions from a table (which stores custom functions and data for players) to a userdata object (which is the main implementation for my Player class) so that users may use `self` to refer to both.

This is how I do my binding in C# in the `Player` class:

```
        state.NewTable("Player");    // Create Player wrapper table
        state["Player.data"] = this; // Bind Player.data to the Player class
        state.NewTable("mt");        // Create temp table for metatable
        state.DoString(@"mt.__index = function(self,key)
                             local k = self.data[key]
                             if key == 'data' or not k then
                                 return rawget(self, key)
                             elseif type(k) ~= 'function' then
                                 print(type(k))
                                 print(k)
                                 return k
                             else
                                 return function(...)
                                     if self == ... then
                                         return k(self.data, select(2,...))
                                     else
                                         return k(...)
                                     end
                                 end
                             end
                         end");
        state.DoString("setmetatable(Player, mt)"); // Change Player's metatable
```

For my `Player` class, I implement a method, `bool IsCommandActive(string name)`. When I need to call this method using `self`, it needs to use the `userdata` object, rather than the table, otherwise I get the following error:

> NLua.Exceptions.LuaScriptException: 'instance method 'IsCommandActive'
>   requires a non null target object'

For obvious reasons. This is because `self` refers to the table, not the userdata. So I implemented a metatable so that it may use `self` to refer to either. The implementation is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11235892/2962027), but here is my particular variant (my userdata is stored in an index called `data`:

```
mt.__index = function(self,key)
    local k = self.data[key]
        if key == 'data' or not k then
            return rawget(self, key)
        elseif type(k) ~= 'function' then
            print(type(k))
            print(k)
            return k
        else
            return function(...)
                if self == ... then
                    return k(self.data, select(2,...))
                else
                    return k(...)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Which I follow by using `setmetatable`, obviously.

Now to the meat of my question. Notice how I print `type(k)` and `print(k)` under the `elseif`. This is because I noticed that I was still getting the same error, so I wanted to do some debugging. When doing so, I got the following output (which I believe is for `IsCommandActive`):

```
userdata: 0BD47190
```

Shouldn't it be printing `'function'`? Why is it printing `'userdata: 0BD47190'`? Finally, if that is indeed the case, how can I detect if the value is a C function so I may do the proper redirection?

Comment: How are you binding this? You've been talking a lot about how you take things out of your table, but not at all about what you put into it in the first place.

Comment: Edited my post to contain this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of reading about metatables, I managed to solve my problem.

To answer the question in the title, it's apparently what NLua just decides to do and is implementation-specific. In any other bindings, it may very well return as `function`, but such is apparently not the case for NLua.

As for how I managed to accomplish what I wanted, I had to define the metatable `__index` and `__newindex` functions:

```
        state.NewTable("Player");
        state["Player.data"] = this;
        state.NewTable("mt");
        state.DoString(@"mt.__index = function(self,key)
                             local k = self.data[key]
                             local metatable = getmetatable(k)
                             if key == 'data' or not k then
                                 return rawget(self, key)
                             elseif type(k) ~= 'function' and (metatable == nil or metatable.__call == nil) then
                                 return k
                             else
                                 return function(...)
                                     if self == ... then
                                         return k(self.data, select(2,...))
                                     else
                                         return k(...)
                                     end
                                 end
                             end
                         end");
        state.DoString(@"mt.__newindex = function(self, key, value)
                             local c = rawget(self, key, value)
                             if not c then
                                 local dataHasKey = self.data[key] ~= key
                                 if not dataHasKey then
                                     rawset(self, key, value)
                                 else
                                     self.data[key] = value
                                 end
                             else
                                 rawset(self, key, value)
                             end
                         end");
        state.DoString("setmetatable(Player, mt)");
```

What `__index` does is override how tables are indexed. In this implementation, if `key` is **not** found in the `Player` wrapper table, then it goes and tries to retrieve it from the `userdata` in `Player.data`. If it doesn't exist there, then Lua just does its thing and returns `nil`.

And just like that, I could retrieve fields from the `userdata`! I quickly began to notice, however, that if I set, for instance, `self.Pos` in Lua, then the `Player.Pos` would *not* update in the backing C# code. Just as quickly, I realized that this was because `Pos` was generating a miss in the `Player` wrapper table, which meant that it was creating a new `Pos` field for the table since it actually did not exist!

This was not the intended behavior, so I had to override `__newindex` as well. In this particular implementation, it checks if the `Player.data` (`userdata`) has the `key`, and if so, sets the data for that particular `key`. If it does not exist in the `userdata`, then it should create it for the `Player` wrapper table because it should be part of the user's custom `Player` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> any functions or objects that are part of a C class are userdata`

This is not true. Function is a function, no matter if it's native or written in Lua. Checking the type of a native function would print "function".

It's just it can be that your binding solution is using `userdata` with `__call` metamethod set on it, to expose a marshaller with some state/context associated with it. But it doesn't mean that every native function is a userdata, or that every binding lib will be implemented same way. It could be done effectively the same using Lua `table` instead of userdata. Would you be telling then that "every native function is a table"? :)

Comment: I did not know that. Now you got me wondering just what NLua does underneath the hood since it was returning `userdata` rather than `function`. I did want to let others know I found the solution to my particular problem, though now there's egg on my face with a wrong answer to the title question.