# what kind of metamethods are these, why they exist and how they are created

Tags: lua, metatable, meta-method

**Hello everyone!**

I've been studying metamethods and I realized something strange!

I already know all the metamethods presented in the Lua documentation as `__add`, `__index`, `__newindex`, etc... But I see around in forums and in questions around here people using metamethods like `__ev` , `__close`, `__group`, and I have never seen anywhere else these metamethods be used or exist in any documentation.

My question is, **these metamethods exists? and if not, how are they created? and why people create this metamethods?**

anyway, thanks for the attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are custom metamethods and have special purpose in specific project or framework.

Metamethods are used to extend functionality of `table` or `userdata`. These are most usable to achieve OOP behavior.

Some programmers add custom metatables and metamethods for internal purpose and better readability, such as `__super`, `__extend`, `__inherit`. In most cases such metadata are used from standard metamethods as `__index`, `__call`, ... or from routine methods to cleanup objects, error handling and so on.

For example `__close` could be used with connection or file objects to manage them in predictible way, `__gc` can't be trusted for this purpose.

Example of `__group` usage: [Lua metatables and metamethod - How to call a different member function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11232680/12918181)

Comment: Extending is the magic what you can do and dont forget the metamethod ```__metatable``` to protect the extensions. Look at a string ```_VERSION``` for example has the __index method as table filled up with ```string``` functions. So with every string you can do the magic: ```print(_VERSION:rep(50))``` The question is: Why dont have the datatype table and integer no metamethods?